# Android 2.2 ndk cmake windows 32 bit

Tags: android, android-ndk

Как настроить cmake для android studio 2.2. В оф. тутуриале написано закачать с sdk tools -> LLDB, CMake, and NDK. Но у меня нет cmake. Система 32 bit. Скачал сайта положил cmake в папку ndk.

При создании проекта возникает такая ошибка:

`External Native Build Issues Build command failed. Error while executing 'D:\SDK\Sdk\cmake\bin\cmake.exe' with arguments {-HD:\ADR\MyApplication4\app -BD:\ADR\MyApplication4\app.externalNativeBuild\cmake\release\armeabi -GAndroid Gradle - Ninja -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi -DANDROID_NDK=D:\SDK\Sdk\ndk-bundle -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=D:\ADR\MyApplication4\app\build\intermediates\cmake\release\obj\armeabi -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=D:\SDK\Sdk\cmake\bin\ninja.exe -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=D:\SDK\Sdk\ndk-bundle\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake -DANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL=17 -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-frtti -fexceptions} CMake Error: Could not create named generator Android Gradle - Ninja Generators Visual Studio 15 2017 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2017 project files. Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM". Visual Studio 14 2015 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2015 project files. Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM". Visual Studio 12 2013 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2013 project files. Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM". Visual Studio 11 2012 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2012 project files. Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM". Visual Studio 10 2010 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2010 project files. Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "IA64". Visual Studio 9 2008 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2008 project files. Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "IA64". Visual Studio 8 2005 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2005 project files. Optional [arch] can be "Win64". Visual Studio 7 .NET 2003 = Deprecated. Generates Visual Studio .NET 2003 project files. Borland Makefiles = Generates Borland makefiles. NMake Makefiles = Generates NMake makefiles. NMake Makefiles JOM = Generates JOM makefiles. Green Hills MULTI = Generates Green Hills MULTI files (experimental, work-in-progress). MSYS Makefiles = Generates MSYS makefiles. MinGW Makefiles = Generates a make file for use with mingw32-make. Unix Makefiles = Generates standard UNIX makefiles. Ninja = Generates build.ninja files. Watcom WMake = Generates Watcom WMake makefiles. CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles = Generates CodeBlocks project files. CodeBlocks - NMake Makefiles = Generates CodeBlocks project files. CodeBlocks - Ninja = Generates CodeBlocks project files. CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles = Generates CodeBlocks project files. CodeLite - MinGW Makefiles = Generates CodeLite project files. CodeLite - NMake Makefiles = Generates CodeLite project files. CodeLite - Ninja = Generates CodeLite project files. CodeLite - Unix Makefiles = Generates CodeLite project files. Sublime Text 2 - MinGW Makefiles = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files. Sublime Text 2 - NMake Makefiles = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files. Sublime Text 2 - Ninja = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files. Sublime Text 2 - Unix Makefiles = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files. Kate - MinGW Makefiles = Generates Kate project files. Kate - NMake Makefiles = Generates Kate project files. Kate - Ninja = Generates Kate project files. Kate - Unix Makefiles = Generates Kate project files. Eclipse CDT4 - NMake Makefiles = Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files. Eclipse CDT4 - MinGW Makefiles = Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files. Eclipse CDT4 - Ninja = Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files. Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles= Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files. Error:executing external native build for cmake D:\ADR\MyApplication4\app\CMakeLists.txt Build command failed. Error while executing 'D:\SDK\Sdk\cmake\bin\cmake.exe' with arguments {-HD:\ADR\MyApplication4\app -BD:\ADR\MyApplication4\app.externalNativeBuild\cmake\debug\armeabi -GAndroid Gradle - Ninja -DANDROID_ABI=armeabi -DANDROID_NDK=D:\SDK\Sdk\ndk-bundle -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=D:\ADR\MyApplication4\app\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\armeabi -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=D:\SDK\Sdk\cmake\bin\ninja.exe -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=D:\SDK\Sdk\ndk-bundle\build\cmake\android.toolchain.cmake -DANDROID_NATIVE_API_LEVEL=17 -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-frtti -fexceptions} CMake Error: Could not create named generator Android Gradle - Ninja Generators Visual Studio 15 2017 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2017 project files. Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM". Visual Studio 14 2015 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2015 project files. Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM". Visual Studio 12 2013 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2013 project files. Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM". Visual Studio 11 2012 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2012 project files. Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "ARM". Visual Studio 10 2010 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2010 project files. Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "IA64". Visual Studio 9 2008 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2008 project files. Optional [arch] can be "Win64" or "IA64". Visual Studio 8 2005 [arch] = Generates Visual Studio 2005 project files. Optional [arch] can be "Win64". Visual Studio 7 .NET 2003 = Deprecated. Generates Visual Studio .NET 2003 project files. Borland Makefiles = Generates Borland makefiles. NMake Makefiles = Generates NMake makefiles. NMake Makefiles JOM = Generates JOM makefiles. Green Hills MULTI = Generates Green Hills MULTI files (experimental, work-in-progress). MSYS Makefiles = Generates MSYS makefiles. MinGW Makefiles = Generates a make file for use with mingw32-make. Unix Makefiles = Generates standard UNIX makefiles. Ninja = Generates build.ninja files. Watcom WMake = Generates Watcom WMake makefiles. CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles = Generates CodeBlocks project files. CodeBlocks - NMake Makefiles = Generates CodeBlocks project files. CodeBlocks - Ninja = Generates CodeBlocks project files. CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles = Generates CodeBlocks project files. CodeLite - MinGW Makefiles = Generates CodeLite project files. CodeLite - NMake Makefiles = Generates CodeLite project files. CodeLite - Ninja = Generates CodeLite project files. CodeLite - Unix Makefiles = Generates CodeLite project files. Sublime Text 2 - MinGW Makefiles = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files. Sublime Text 2 - NMake Makefiles = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files. Sublime Text 2 - Ninja = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files. Sublime Text 2 - Unix Makefiles = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files. Kate - MinGW Makefiles = Generates Kate project files. Kate - NMake Makefiles = Generates Kate project files. Kate - Ninja = Generates Kate project files. Kate - Unix Makefiles = Generates Kate project files. Eclipse CDT4 - NMake Makefiles = Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files. Eclipse CDT4 - MinGW Makefiles = Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files. Eclipse CDT4 - Ninja = Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files. Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles= Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files. Error:executing external native build for cmake D:\ADR\MyApplication4\app\CMakeLists.txt`

Comment: Проще будет если вы напишите, что вы в итоге хотите сделать. Сейчас cmake можно настроить, несколькими мне известными путями, дальше он может использовать в нескольких местах, а есть вариант что вы вообще его не увидите.

Comment: В Android studio 2.2 есть галочка включить c++. Я скачал ndk LLDB. Но CMAKE в sdk tools нет.  Как его настроить отдельно.